# Reading from a redirected stdin (wordcount) - C

Tags: c, redirect, stdin

I have this text file called "input.txt" which contains:

```
test line one
test line two
final line
```

After compiling and running via

```
$ ./a.exe < input.txt
```

I get the output:

```
33 8 0
```

I'm confused as to why the line count doesn't work as when I print out the integer values, 13 and 10 (carriage return/line feed) are shown. Also charcount is two over the actual count. Any ideas?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(void) { 
        int charcount = 0, wordcount = 0, linecount = 0; 
        int c = getchar();    

        while (c != EOF){
            if (c == 13){
                linecount++;
                c = getchar();
            } else if (c >= 65 && c <= 90 || c >= 97 && c <= 122 || c == 39 && c != 13) {  
                while (c >= 65 && c <= 90 || c >= 97 && c <= 122 || c == 39 && c != 13){
                    charcount++;                
                    c = getchar();
                }
                wordcount++;
            } else {
                charcount++;
            }
            c = getchar(); 
        }

        printf("%lu %lu %lu\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount);

        return (0);
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget that newlines are characters too.  The standard `wc` program certainly counts them; your code probably should too.  On Unix, your file has two lines with 13 characters and one with 10, plus 3 newlines, for a total of 39 characters; on Windows, a text file will appear to have 39 characters too, though there'll be 42 characters on disk or in the file if it is treated as a binary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a text file on Windows is processed in C, the CRLF line endings are mapped to `'\n'` (newline) only endings.  And `'\n'` is 10 (<kbd>Control-J</kbd>) and not 13 (<kbd>Control-M</kbd>).  That's probably why you're seeing 0 for the line count.

You should not be coding the conditions as you did (unless you've got a sadistic teacher who tells you to do it like that).  Use the `<ctype.h>` and `isalpha()` (and `c == '\''` instead of `39`).

You could debug by adding a print statement (`printf("^M read\n");`) in the `if (c == 13)` code.